# Function mirrored around $y = x$

Tags: functions

How do we know, for a function $f$, if the function graph mirrored around the line $y = x$ can be defined as another function $g$ ?

For example, we can see in the image below the function $f=e^x$ mirrored can be described as $g(x) = ln(x)$:

[image]

But to provide a simple example, the function $f(x) = 0$ mirrored can only be described as a straight line up, but cannot be described as a function.

Comment: I recommend you study what injections, surjections and bijections are.

Comment: your zero function is not bijective.

Comment: The mirrored version of $f$ will be a function (with a potentially limited domain) if and only if $f$ is **one-to-one**.  In other words, $f$ needs to *pass the horizontal line test*.

Comment: By the way, since you're might interested in "pretty" mirrored functions, this is an (unexpectedly?) bijective function: $y = 1 + x + \cos(x) \sin(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be a function, a relation must associate each value of the domain with a single value of the codomain.  Your question is essentially what property must a function have to have an inverse which is also a function

So to have a complete inverse, a function must be both surjective (so every value of the codomain can come back) and injective (so it comes back to a single value), i.e. bijective

Your $\exp$ and $\log$ example only works if you treat them as $\exp: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $\log: \mathbb{R}_{>0} \to \mathbb{R}$, in which case the domain and codomain is different.  This may not be what you intended

Answer (score 0):

must be $f(x_1)\ne f(x_2)$ for every $x_1,x_2$, so as Eemil said injection required

Answer (score 0):

If the graph of function $g$ is the reflection of $f$ across the line y=x, then $g$ is inverse of $f$

If $f(x)$ takes some $x$ to some value $y,$ then $g(y)$ takes $y$ back to $x.$

Or, $g(f(x)) = x.$

Or, $(g\circ f)x = x$

Or, $g(x) = f^{-1}(x)$

When is g a "function"?

$f$ is a function if for every $y$ ind the range, there is at most one $x$ in the domain.

If $g$ takes every $y$ back to it's respective $x, g$ can only be a function, if every $y$ maps to at most one $x.$

If every $x$ maps to at most one $y$ and every $y$ maps to at most one $x$ we call the function "injective" or  "one to one" or "1-1."